# Getting One or more recipients are invalid error

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-flow, send-email

I am trying to send an email to the Shared mailbox. It is hard coded in the flow but when I try to send an email, it gives the

> One or more recipients are invalid error.

I am able to send email to that shared mailbox using my outlook client but not using power automate.

I tried with `SP.Utility` and Send Email Outlook actions and in both of them the same error is occurring.

Can anyone help here to identify what is going wrong?

Comment: Is it user account or security group or shared mailbox or something else?

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, Yes, It is a Shared mailbox. I updated the question for the same.